# Intuition For Overlapping Confidence Intervals and Statistical Significance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Two questions:

1. I have a really hard time with the intuition for why the second part
   of this statement is true:

   > If two statistics have non-overlapping confidence intervals, they are
   >   necessarily significantly different, but if they have overlapping
   >   confidence intervals, it is not necessarily true that they are not
   >   significantly different.
2. Would it be correct to say that a little overlap doesn't go a long way? Is there a rule of thumb for what degree of overlap implies no difference?

---

Here's a simple example where looking at overlapping confidence intervals gives the wrong idea. The outcome is a self-reported happiness rating on 7 point Likert scale that I will treat as continuous. The explanatory variables is martial status, gender, age and race. I will use OLS:

```
. webuse set http://www.stata-press.com/data/ivrm
(prefix now "http://www.stata-press.com/data/ivrm")

. webuse "gss_ivrm.dta", clear

. reg happy7 i.marital i.female i.race c.age

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =    1156
-------------+------------------------------           F(  8,  1147) =    7.35
       Model |  53.9791041     8  6.74738801           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  1052.29339  1147  .917431026           R-squared     =  0.0488
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.0422
       Total |  1106.27249  1155  .957811681           Root MSE      =  .95783

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        happy7 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       marital |
      widowed  |  -.4531618    .123599    -3.67   0.000    -.6956673   -.2106563
     divorced  |   -.499064   .0795273    -6.28   0.000    -.6550994   -.3430287
    separated  |  -.5496177   .1699695    -3.23   0.001    -.8831036   -.2161317
never married  |   -.155781   .0761826    -2.04   0.041    -.3052539   -.0063082
               |
        female |
       Female  |   .1196351   .0580584     2.06   0.040     .0057225    .2335476
               |
          race |
        black  |  -.0354866   .0850047    -0.42   0.676    -.2022688    .1312956
        other  |  -.1123621   .1179656    -0.95   0.341    -.3438146    .1190905
               |
           age |   .0050064    .002079     2.41   0.016     .0009273    .0090854
         _cons |   5.415511   .1130652    47.90   0.000     5.193673    5.637349
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I will compute adjusted means for each possible state:

```
. margins marital

Predictive margins                                Number of obs   =       1156
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               |            Delta-method
               |     Margin   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       marital |
      married  |   5.698407   .0408098   139.63   0.000     5.618336    5.778477
      widowed  |   5.245245   .1178389    44.51   0.000     5.014041    5.476449
     divorced  |   5.199342   .0684853    75.92   0.000     5.064972    5.333713
    separated  |   5.148789   .1647873    31.25   0.000     4.825471    5.472107
never married  |   5.542625   .0630837    87.86   0.000     5.418853    5.666398
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The CIs for separated and never married overlap by a tiny bit. However, when I do the formal test, I get

```
. margins ar.marital, contrast(nowald pveffects)

Contrasts of predictive margins
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()

----------------------------------------------------------------------
                              |            Delta-method
                              |   Contrast   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|
------------------------------+---------------------------------------
                      marital |
        (widowed vs married)  |  -.4531618    .123599    -3.67   0.000
       (divorced vs widowed)  |  -.0459022   .1339294    -0.34   0.732
     (separated vs divorced)  |  -.0505536   .1784857    -0.28   0.777
(never married vs separated)  |   .3938366   .1761455     2.24   0.026
```

The CIs for divorced and windowed overlap by a lot, and the contrast is not significant.

Comment: See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/60793/1036) for a few references of interest. I've also pointed people towards *Using Confidence Intervals for 
Graphically Based Data Interpretation* [(Masson & Loftus, 2003)](http://web.uvic.ca/psyc/masson/ML03.pdf) as well. Last time I looked on google scholar there were many similar papers in other fields as well - no economics that I remember though ;). IMO you should upload the pictures of the plots.

Comment: Your first question is answered in [several threads here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confidence-interval?sort=votes&pageSize=50). The second is addressed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18259.