# Subject-specific graphics for repeated-measure design

Tags: r, data-visualization, mixed-model, ggplot2, treatment-effect

I am doing linear mixed effect modelling testing the effect of `treatment` on `pitch`, with `repetitions` nested inside `items`, in turn nested within `speakers`.

I am looking for ways to present my data like in the following graph, x-axis marking `treatment` in my case and ColorScheme marking `item`. I have 10 speakers, so I want to generate 10 graphs, preferably all shown together or in two pages. Is this doable?

[image: effect I want to achieve]

Data:
[image]

Note on my data:

1. `tone` is the treatment
2. `int` is the five sample points I take on a repetition, which for graphics purpose should be averaged?
3. `semitone` is the dependant variable
4. I want `speaker` to go on the x-axis
5. I want `item` to be on the ColorScheme (there are three items)
6. I want `repetitions` averaged for graphics purpose.

Part of actual data can be found in https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Q7ztgF6nEPNWtqRnRsSW1RU0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: I have attached my data, appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to paste the data as a text rather then image..?

Comment: I can't keep the format in the post, very likely due to my incompetence. I've uploaded it to Google drive. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Q7ztgF6nEPNWtqRnRsSW1RU0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There are potentially two separate questions here; how to effectively present the data and what error bars to show. Both have come up numerous times on this site. See related on plotting the individual observations and avoiding dynamite plots ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584329/how-to-avoid-overplotting-for-points-using-base-graph), [2](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22733/1036), [3](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1173/1036)).

Comment: For what standard errors to show, see ([1](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/60767/1036),[2](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2067/1036)).